# WordPress Live Search Results Redirect to Homepage

Tags: php, database, wordpress, search, echo

When I click on any search result on [Helena Recipes search bar in top menu](https://www.helenarecipes.com) I am automatically redirected to the homepage instead of the corresponding post. Thumbnails do not show up either (although they should, next to the titles).

I tried switching themes and testing plugins. None of them seem to be the reason. I then edited the searchform.php code by adding:

```
  name="s"
```

But it does not help. This is the code I have in the searchform.php:

```
  <form method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="search-field-w">
      <input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder', 'osetin' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'osetin' ) ?>" />
      <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'osetin' ) ?>" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

And this is the code I have in my search.php:

```
  <?php
  /**
   * The template for displaying search results page
  */

  get_header(); 

  $layout_type_for_index = osetin_get_settings_field('layout_type_for_index');

  ?>
  <div class="os-container">
    <div class="page-intro-header without-background">
      <h2><?php printf( __( '"%s" <span class="smaller-text">Query Search Results</span>', 'osetin' ), ucwords(get_search_query()) ); ?></h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os-container">
    <?php global $wp_query; ?>
    <?php echo build_index_posts($layout_type_for_index, 'sidebar-index', $wp_query); ?>
  </div>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However, the search.php is about showing the results of a different search (you can see it in the bottom of [the main page](https://www.helenarecipes.com)), right before the footer, and it works fine. The issue is in the "live" search functionality as it is supposed to take you to the corresponding post.

What am I missing?

Comment: if you have search.php file in your theme?

Comment: Any filter functions applied for redirect search page to home page ?

Comment: @developerme Yes I do. I have edited my initial post with the code from search.php

Comment: @ravipatel The search shows results as I type. Once I press any of them it should take me directly to that post (you can see that when you hover over any of the results you get the right link) so it shouldn't even take me to the search page. However as soon as I click the result it goes straight to the homepage.

Comment: I looked at your website. the problem is not with your serachbar. **problem with thumbnails**: they are loading through `http://` protocol instead of `https://`. that's why you can't see them. **problem with redirect** from searchform to homepage: it's look like some `.htaccess` rules: all results from search is with `http://` protocol and after clicking on them the website just redirects from `http://{your-website}/{some-post}` to homepage. how do you defined redirect rules?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan You are right! It as an HTTPS issue with thumbnails. I've tried all possible variations of .htaccess rewrite codes  - nothing works until I've installed the plugin called Really Simple SSL. I've checked the .htaccess file and nothing changed there but apparently the plugin changed http to https somewhere and it got the search working. Thank you for taking time to look into the issue and helping solve it.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I need to accept the best answer and I think it is your comment that helped me the most. Would you like to make it as a separate answer, and I will vote for it and accept as the best one?

Comment: I added my answer. glad to help

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Thanks, but I mentioned that the plugin actually helped me. Not vice versa. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your website. The problem is not with your search bar.

Issue with thumbnails: they are loading through `http://` protocol instead of `https://`. And this is causing `Mixed content` errors, which stops loading images. That's why you can't see them.

The problem with redirect from search form to homepage: it's look like some `.htaccess` rules: all result *pages/posts* from search is with `http://` protocol and after clicking on them the website just redirects from `http://{your-website}/{some-post}` to homepage. It can be done through `.htaccess` rules, with some `javascript`, with `php` and from the database.

Comment: You got it a bit wrong - "Really Simple SSL" plugin helped to solve the issue, not vice versa. Not sure if you can edit that in your answer to give the plugin author proper credit? But the rest of your thoughts really helped me to find the solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@jack : You are using URL with http instead try with https as your domain has SSL certificate installed. So, http will not work.

http://www.helenarecipes.com/recipe/peaches-tomatoes-quinoa-salad/

instead try below URL in search listing

https://www.helenarecipes.com/recipe/peaches-tomatoes-quinoa-salad/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @RajdipChauchan Really appreciate your input.

Comment: @jack : please accept and vote up the answer if it's help you.